# How to animate a flot piechart?

Tags: jquery, animation, flot, pie-chart

Is it possible to animate a flot piechart?  I am particularly interested in animation that shows loading piechart as it spins clockwise.  Other kinds of animation can be of interest too

Comment: http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/Spiral.html

Comment: This spiral works well but I do not see the option to show numbers on the resulted chart